# How does rasa form keep asking questions in a loop？

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I now want to implement the following functions through rasa

```
User:How is the weather in New York today?
Bot:New York today is sunny.
User:How about Washington?
Bot:Washington today is rain
User:How about London
Bot:London today is cloudy
User:What about tomorrow?
Bot:London tomorrow is sunny
User:How about New York?
Bot:New York tomorrow is rain
......
```

This conversation can continue to loop until the user’s intention changes.I am using the form in rasa, but the form can only be looped for one round. After all the slots are filled, it is deactivated. So is there a better way to achieve this function? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine that the form is deactivated each time; it will just be reactivated when the user provides a relevant input.  In the final action of your form, you can reset whichever slots you want to `None`. Then if the user asks the same kind of question again, the form will start over with empty slots. Even without resetting the slots, if the user provided an input that filled the slot with a new value, that new value will be used by the form.

Comment: Thanks for you reply . I will have a try.

Comment: How to activate loop from custom action on session start without specific intent?